# Webpack require.context Pre-load Dynamic Assets

Tags: webpack

I'm using Webpack to create a collection of games. I would like to pre-load the assets (.svg files) based on run time configuration. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
let requestGameAssets = require["context"]('../../../resources/html5Images/gameAssets', true, /.+\/.*/);
```

I'm not 100% clear on weather this creates a bundle that includes all my assets? or is this only a wrapper that allows resolving to each of the included assets. e.g. once you call that first asset will be loaded?:

```
requestGameAssets(requestGameAssets.keys()[0]);
```

Secondly this second call doesn't seem to result in anything being loaded! I am still required to use the full path to the asset not just the key in the context otherwise it gives me a 404. If I do use the full path to the asset it seems to load that asset at that time. In other words the context doesn't give me anything.. If there is a way to include assets from a context in css that would also be really helpful.

This seems like a reasonably common used case if someone could point me to an example of this that would be great. Webpack documentation focuses more on loading code modules than the assets.

Cheers
Rod